# Why does "curl" command work normally while "ping" not?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, ping, curl

I find a strange phenomenon in my corporate network:
I can execute `curl google.com` command successfully:

```
[root@localhost ~]# curl google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

But execute `ping google.com` failed:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping google.com
PING google.com (173.194.33.174) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
1569 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1568463ms
```

I suspect the sysadmin has done something, but not sure. Could anyone give some clues how to debug this issue? For example, does the sysadmin set some rules which can filter `ping` command? How can I verify it?

Comment: ICMP blocked by corporate firewall most likely. Can you successfully ping any site?

Comment: @Karan: No. Can't ping any foreign sites successfully. How can verify this?

Comment: I'm not sure at your end how you can confirm this since the firewall config will surely be inaccessible to you, but it is the most likely cause.

Answer (score 4):

You could test if ICMP is blocked with the following perl program:

**ping.pl** (Edited to print port)

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl    
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Ping;

my @hosts = @ARGV;
die "usage: sudo perl ping.pl host\n" unless @ARGV;

my $timeout = 5;
my @proto = ("tcp", "udp", "icmp","syn");
foreach my $pro ( @proto ) {

    my $p = Net::Ping->new($pro);

    # default port    
    my $port = 7;
    $p->port_number($port);

    # tcp on https port
    if ( $pro eq "tcp"){
      $port = 443;
      $p->port_number($port);
    }

    print "\nProtocol $pro port $port\n";
    foreach my $host( @hosts ) {    
      if ($p->ping($host, $timeout)){
        print "$host is reachable\n";
      }
      else{
        print "$host is NOT reachable\n";
      }
    }
    $p->close();
    sleep(2);
}
exit;
```

---

```sh
#$ sudo perl ping.pl  google.com 

Protocol tcp port 443
google.com is reachable

Protocol udp port 7
google.com is NOT reachable

Protocol icmp port 7
google.com is reachable

Protocol syn port 7
google.com is reachable
```

---

**ping and curl output (videotron network)**

```
#$ ping -c 4 google.com
PING google.com (24.200.237.84) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from google-084.237.cache.videotron.ca (24.200.237.84):    icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=7.14 ms
64 bytes from google-084.237.cache.videotron.ca (24.200.237.84):    icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=10.1 ms
64 bytes from google-084.237.cache.videotron.ca (24.200.237.84):    icmp_seq=3 ttl=61 time=6.86 ms
64 bytes from google-084.237.cache.videotron.ca (24.200.237.84): icmp_seq=4 ttl=61 time=8.86 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.866/8.243/10.102/1.320 ms

#$ curl google.com
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.ca/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=ArVmVbiOLajd8gfKq4DoCQ">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: So if host is not reachable for any reason that necessarily means ICMP is blocked at your end?

Comment: @David L.: After executing the script, it outputs:"` [root@mawent3 ~]# ./ping.pl google.com Protocol tcp google.com is NOT reachable Protocol udp google.com is NOT reachable
Protocol icmp google.com is NOT reachable
Protocol syn google.com is reachable`", what does it can prove?

Comment: @Nan Xiao as it was suggested in the comments to your question, ICMP is probably blocked by corporate  firewall

Comment: @DavidL: Why `curl` can success? It seems both `tcp` and `udp` are blocked too.

Comment: @Nan Xiao The perl program is not making a request like curl. It is possible that the firewall from your network allow only connection to port 80. ping and curl give different results from my ISP.